# How to avoid having file location in my code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have something like

```
Workbooks.Open("\\xxxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\file_name.xlsm")
```

I want this to be hidden from my code, but I do not know where to start, or whether what I'm asking for really exist.

Edit: just to be more clear. I don't want people to easily see the file locations in my code.

Comment: And how should the code know the location? I guess the best bet is to protect the code.

Comment: Store it in named range and access through that

Comment: Have the code written to operate on the only open workbook.

Comment: Why not just password protect the VBA?

Answer (score 1):

You could set an environment variable, `myFilePath`, with value `\\xxxx\...\file_name.xlsm`. Then, in your code, access this value with `Environ("myFilePath")`.

Comment: Interesting. Gonna look into this.

Comment: That takes 10 seconds more for someone who has access to your code to figure out the path...

Comment: @FunThomas Yes true xD how about a config file? could this be done in VBA?

Comment: @Brainiac: Sure, pretty easy (see for example here: https://stackoverflow.com
/questions/11528694/read-parse-text-file-line-by-line-in-vba). However, if someone looks at the code, she/he can see that you are reading the file, look to it and again knows the path. I think the best bet is that you password-protect the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think users can easily see the file location after it is opened through the Save As dialog or File > Advanced Properties. To avoid that you can look into opening the file as template with [`Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.add) instead of Open :

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Add("\\xxxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\file_name.xlsm")
```

---

To add a hidden value to a workbook, it can be added as a hidden Name ( execute code only once ) :

```
 Names.Add("path", "test").Visible = False
```

After it is added, `Names("Path")` will result in `="test"` instead of just `test`, so to get the value you can try something like (assuming there are no `"` in the path ) :

```
 path = Split(Names("Path"), """")(1)

 Set wb = Workbooks.Add(path)
```